# Which of the following lines offers the better fit to the given points in the least-squares?

Tags: numerical-methods, least-squares, numerical-calculus, error-propagation

I have two similar exercises:

> Which of the following lines, $y = 1 - x$ or $y = 4 - x$, offers the better fit to the points $(1,2),(2,1), (3,1)$ in the least-squares?
> Justify?

My thought process (haven't solved it yet) was to solve for $A^tAx=A^tb$ and find the line that best approximates it, and then for each point find the error... but now I see that doesn't make much sense. I might not have to solve that system because on this other exercise:

> Determine and justify, without solving any system of equations, which
> line $y = -1 -x$ or $y = 1-x$ offers the better fit, in the least squares,
> the points $(-2,3),(-1,2),(0,1),(1,0)$.

How do I solve this? I remember vaguely some formula that involved a sum of the residue or error or something, and squares, but I don't remember it well.

Comment: Just to clarify the question, the question must mean which of those two lines offers the *better* fit. The actual best-fit line or the three points is neither of those.

Comment: @MatthewDaly yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one can be solved without computation at all.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly $4-x$ is the better fit in the least-square sense.  Maybe we'd rather have a formula.  For each point, compute the square of the difference between the height of the point and the height of the line.

- $1-x$: $((1-\overbrace{1}^{x_1})-\overbrace{2}^{y_1})^2 + ((1-2)-1)^2 + ((1-3)-1)^2 = 4 + 4 + 9 = 17$.
- $4-x$: $((4-1)-2)^2 + ((4-2)-1)^2 + ((4-3)-1)^2 = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2$.

This computation confirms that $4-x$ is a better fit to the data in the least squares sense.

As a formula, the quantity to minimize is
$$  \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - y_i)^2  \text{,}  $$
where $\{(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)\}$ is the set of points being fit and $f$ is (in these examples) the line.

The second one is even easier -- all the point lie on one of the lines.

Comment: Are you sure the formula isn't the other way around? $\sum_{i=1}^n ( y_i-f(x_i))^2  \text{,}$

Comment: @Segmentationfault:  $(f(x_i)-y_i)^2=(y_i-f(x_i))^2$

Comment: @Segmentationfault :  $(y_i - f(x_i))^2 = (f(x_i) - y_i)^2$.  The squaring deletes any information about the sign (i.e., the order of the minuend and subtrahend).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh. Silliness. Thanks guys.